# iOS7 Call an IBAction method also from ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

So I have a view with a button which calls an IBAction method with this method signature and it works just fine from the button.

```
-(IBAction)getCurrentConditions:(id)sender
```

I also want to call the same method from within ViewDidLoad. What do I pass in the (id)sender parameter since I don't need to pass anything from ViewDidLoad.

Comment: `[self getCurrentConditions:nil]`, except if in `getCurrentConditions` you use `sender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass `nil` or pass `self.someButton` if you have a property reference to the button. Of course passing `nil` only works if the method doesn't really need the sender. Then again, if the method doesn't need the sender, why bother having the parameter at all?

```
[self getCurrentCondition:self.someButton];
```

or

```
[self getCurrentCondition:nil];
```

Or change the signature to:

```
- (IBAction)getCurrentCondition {
    // Do stuff that doesn't need the sender
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sender is normally the 'IBOutlet' that sends the message, for example, a UIButton. So you can just link that button to your view controller and set that to be the sender. Or if you are doing nothing about the sender you can just send nil.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, IBAction methods called from .xib file but you can call it from anywhere in your implementation file by using a selector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(getCurrentConditions:) withObject:self.curConditionBtn afterDelay:0.0f];
```

Comment: Curious - why use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` over calling the method directly?

Comment: just another way to do call the method... calling the method directly can be used also..